# How to lookup a url on a page

Tags: php, url, lookup

I'm new to Regular Expressions and things like that. I have only few knowledge and I think my current problem is about them.

I have a webpage, that contains text. I want to get links from the webpage that are only in `SPAN`s that have `class="img"`.

I go through those steps.

1. grab all the `SPAN`s tagged with the "img" class (this is the hard step that I'm looking for)
2. move those `SPAN`s to a new variable
3. Parse the variable to get an array with the links (Each `SPAN` has only 1 link, so this will be easy)

I'm using PHP, but any other language doesn't matter, I'm looking how to deal with the first step. Any one have a suggestion?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use PHPs [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)-class in combination with the [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)-class to navigate to the elements you need, like this:

`<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://foo.bar'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);`

$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body//span[@class='img']//a");
foreach ($elements as $a)
{
    echo $a->getAttribute('href'), "\n";
}

[You can learn more about the XPath Language on the W3C page.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)

Comment: +1 I agree, page scraping is much more fun with DOM parsing as opposed to regexes.

Comment: +1 although it will only work on well formed XHTML documents.

Comment: Thanks, I just knew how Xpath is useful :)

Comment: 1- change the 'img' to "img"
2- this give a plenty of warnings, how to disable them? (but it works and gives the results needed)

Comment: 'img' should work just aswell. To disable the warnings prefix an @ before the $dom->loadHTML() like this: @$dom->loadHTML($html);

Comment: the 'img' don't work, you need "img" (u already used the '')
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\Program Files\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\grab.php on line 9

Answer (score 1):

A pattern like `<span.* class="img".*>([^<]*)</span>` should work fine., assuming your code looks something like

```
<span class="img">http://www.img.com/img.jpg</span>
<span alt="yada" class="img">animage.png</span>
<span alt="yada" class="img" title="still works">link.txt</span>
<span>not an img class</span>


<?php

$pattern = '@<span.* class="img".*>([^<]*)</span>@i';

//$subject = html code above

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

Comment: this shows the complete span :)
any way that's a good starting point
I choose to work with this because it's safer if my page don't load completely :D

Comment: I think $matches[0] will contain the full match (e.g. <span...</span>) but $matches[1] will contain the first captured expression: the bit inside the <span>

Comment: Using the DOM definitely represents a better solution, I agree, if the right extensions are available and the markup is valid.

Comment: your matches is a jagged array
$matches[0] = array containing the findings
$matches[1] = empty

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using PHP, but any other language
>   doesn't matter, I'm looking how to
>   deal with the first step. Any one have
>   a suggestion?

We-e-ell...

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
sieve = SoupStrainer(name='span', attrs={'class': 'img'})
tag_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parseOnlyThese=sieve)
for link in tag_soup('a'):
    print link['href']
```

(that's python, using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) - should work on most douments, well-formed or no).

Comment: you get links from this 'soup' i'll look if there's something alike in PHP it's very useful